# Which AWS resources are supported by AWS OpsWorks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-opsworks, amazon-vpc

I am looking for an infra management tool in AWS and stumbled upon OpsWorks.It looks promising as it uses Chef for config management which suits me. The only caveat is that in the documentation of OpsWorks the following is mentioned :

> Compared to AWS CloudFormation, AWS OpsWorks supports a narrower range
>   of application-oriented AWS resource types including Amazon EC2
>   instances, Amazon EBS volumes, Elastic IPs, and Amazon CloudWatch
>   metrics.

I tried searching but could not find the **exhaustive** list of AWS resources which are supported by OpsWorks. I would be requiring VPC's, subnets, NAT instances, Internet Gateways, Virtual Private Gateways, Vpc-to-Vpc peering and so on.

Does anyone have an idea as to what is supported and what is not?

Answer (score 1):

Opsworks is more for deployment automation / server bootstrapping, not for building the whole environment. It will work with the rest of aws resources. One of limitations is that once you spin up instances via opsworks, you have to manage them via opsworks and can't use ec2 autoscaling groups, though opsworks does offer its own autoscaling functionality - both load and time based.

If you want to automate building the whole environment including VPC, nat instances etc, you should use cloudformation or develop your own custom script using amazon cli / or sdk http://aws.amazon.com/tools/

Answer (score 0):

What that refers to is GUI / integration between those resources to what is enabled in Opsworks .

For example : A year ago when Opsworks first launched, it did not "support" ELB for servers in a layer. That means that there was no GUI / easy option for someone to configure up all the instances a layer to be tied to an ELB. You could manually configure a recipe to run and register the instances to the ELB.

Recently RDS was added as a service on Opsworks. You can provide the mysql details rds root, and register it with a stack. You would have easily manually configured these things before.

All AWS services are usable. You could easily configure the VPC etc . You would have to manually handle things like : vpc peering, etc.

The most significant restrictions is the narrorwer range of EC2 instance sizes available. Most general

Answer (score 0):

Set to tools that can be use to build in infrastructure is following 
Boto: good if you want to stand a stable long running AWS infrastructure: This is easy and good amount of google resources are available to help.

troposphere: if you are standing an dynamic infrastructure then use cloudformation. however cloudformation (basically a json database) works with Json data fragments. So would can user troposphere to produce that json data. Troposphere is python library. 
https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere